# Phlex http access on Apache (windows)

Tags: windows, apache

I've had no luck in getting various services/chromecast to talk to [Phlex](https://github.com/d8ahazard/Phlex) through the docker installation. Therefore, I've tried to use xxamp's apache server instead.

However, it does not load `localhost/Phlex` page, throwing a `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`. Apparently, this is due to [gzip problems](https://stefantsov.com/fixing-err_content_decoding_failed-in-apachephp/) and the fix is turn it off. However, I can't find anywhere to do that apart from `ngix.conf`, which has no effect.

Oh and the logs are empty apart from:

```
[31-Aug-2017 09:47:46] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 296
[31-Aug-2017 09:47:46] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Aug-2017 09:47:53] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[31-Aug-2017 09:47:53] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Aug-2017 09:48:21] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 273
[31-Aug-2017 09:48:21] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Aug-2017 09:57:13] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[31-Aug-2017 09:57:13] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```

And there is no `.htaccess file`

So finally I added the `zlib.output_compression = On` line and the page loaded but with the following errors which block the GUI to the point of unusability.

And of course, chromecast is not found... again

```
Warning: ob_start(): output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phlex\index.php on line 16

Notice: ob_start(): failed to create buffer in C:\xampp\htdocs\phlex\index.php on line 16
```

Has anyone done this successfully?